# vertical alignment with other blocks: coded buttons in mailchimp

Tags: html, button, mailchimp

I found an answer on how to put 2 Mailchimp buttons next to each other already via code:

[Mailchimp code to make two button next to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198622/mailchimp-code-to-make-two-button-next-to-each-other/48198662#48198662?newreg=a2b509347cb94a9e8be0e7a1c7fd8081)

Thank you for the answer!

However, I have a problem with the **vertical alignment** (not sure whether this is the right term). The buttons go further right and further left than the rest of my campaign blocks. Can someone help?

There is a screenshot to show the problem (see below).

Thanks in advance!
Rhea

[Screenshot vertical button alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUFrk.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. Still don't know, what did the trick exactly (maybe the class?) but it works:

I just copied the HTML-code for the "button block" from an old campaign and adjusted it to my needs. (see screenshot). Now the blocks align vertically.

Hope it helps someone sometime ;)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PX4PR.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).